# problem while updating package

Tags: apt, updates

So i tried to update my package and here its says that

```
Err:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian hirsute Release 404  Not Found [IP: 108.158.251.124 443]
```

so what does this problem exactly mean and how to solve this?
and i am newbie in linux so please tell me what does this "doesn't have release file mean"?"s not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
" and and what does this mean too?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: That source provides support for Debian releases only if you look, open the link up with a browser & peek in the dists/ folder for supported releases. You'll quickly note **no** Ubuntu support is provided there, but I hope your box is offline given some patches for *hirsute* were dropped as it reached EOL prior to their time required to be in -proposed was completed; users having got their patches post-upgrade to 21.10 or *impish*.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10, since 21.04 is out of support.

Then, your repo string is wrong. The Docker repo for Ubuntu Impish should be: (after you upgrade to a supported release)

```
deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu impish stable
```

So you should edit your `sources.list` to have the correct string. The source file will most likely be either `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`.

[See instructions here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).